# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Can someone please explain why I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined` when I use this syntax

```
const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(function(item) {
  return (
    <TodoItem
      key={item.id}
      item={item}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  );
})
```

But no error when I use the arrow pointer syntax as shown below

```
const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(
  item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
)
```

Note: i have used `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` inside the `constructor()` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your map function to `this`, otherwise `this` is undefined:

```
const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(function(item){
    return (
        <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
    )
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Can you explain why? Because i already did that in the constructor ```this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)```  .Or is this something else? I am quite new here

Comment: @VishruthSubramanian This is binding the `this` of the component to the anonymous callback function used by `map`. If you define the map callback outside in your component like any other class function then it'd be more like how you bound `this` to `handleChange` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring is the exact reason Arrow Functions Expressions were introduced to Javascript.
In Javascript every function has a scope in which "this" is defined.
This means that:

```
function f1() {
   this.name = "John";
   function f2() {
     // here this.name is undefined
     this.name = "Doe"
     // here this.name is "Doe"

   }
   // here this.name "John"
}
```

You might want to read
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

The difference is how `this` works with functions in JS. This explanation comes from [this source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/)

In classic function expressions, the `this` keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which it is called. With arrow functions however, this is lexically bound. It means that it usesthis from the code that contains the arrow function.

For example, look at the setTimeout function below:

```js
// ES5
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
};
```

In the ES5 example, .bind(this) is required to help pass the this context into the function. Otherwise, by default this would be `undefined`.

```js
// ES6
var obj = {
  id: 42,
  counter: function counter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.id);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

ES6 arrow functions can’t be bound to a this keyword, so it will lexically go up a scope, and use the value of this in the scope in which it was defined.

[Source to explanation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/)